# Vue.js component white screen

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I got a white screen in my simple demo component and I have not any idea what is wrong with my code.

**Dashboard.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.vue'
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components : {
        Dashboard
    }
})
```

Just white screen, components are not present in DOM. Vue2.X

Comment: you have no render function in your main.js

Comment: Do note that the `id="app"` won't work for the renderer. As Vue still needs to render the div

Comment: Add `template: "<Dashboard />"` to the object you pass in main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in your **main.js**, there's no render function in yours:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(Dashboard)
}).$mount("#app");
```